# Zend Framework 2 Rewrite URL

Tags: .htaccess, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have a Zend Framework 2 app and I wish to use .htaccess to rewrite some URLs.
The .htaccess file is in my public folder.
I have verified a simple rewrite rule which rewrites all testurl to test.php

```
RewriteRule ^testurl/?$ test.php [NC]
```

The test.php file is also in the public folder.
I placed this rule above the Zend rule to map all URLs to index.php in .htaccess.

My question is how do i rewrite this to say the SearchController in the Index Module?
I have tried various rewrite rules with different flags such as

```
RewriteRule ^testurl/?$ /index/search [NC]
and
RewriteRule ^testurl/?$ index/search [NC]
```

but i always get the 404 error
**The requested URL could not be matched by routing.**

The reason i wish to use .htaccess is that i'll be using a regex in the rewrite rule to catch a few different URLs.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either want:

```
RewriteRule ^testurl/?$ /index/search [NC,L,R]
```

Or you need to add a route for `testurl` in zend and route it to the SearchController.

Comment: Many thanks. That works great. I had tried the flags [NC,L] but it didn;t work and i thought the L was the problem as the URL would need to be catered for by the Zend rewrite rules, which are below this one in my .htaccess.  Why does the R, which i understand to be a temp redirect to URL make this work? Once again many thanks

Comment: @user12345 without the `R`, it internally rewrites the URI. This usually means there has to be a physical resource at `/index/search`, but what you have here is a Zend route, and it needs to go through Zend's routing system in order to be interpreted correctly. Internal rewrites aren't usually going to cut it, so an external redirect is needed. Or, you can create a new route, or use the `P` flag which reverse proxies the request and won't change the URL in the browser's address bar (will only work with mod_proxy loaded)

Comment: Ah i see. I think the P flag is what i;m looking for as i want the URL to remain the same. Many thanks