# Zend Framework 2 URL Rewrites

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework, mod-rewrite, zend-framework2

I'm using the Zend Framework 2 and the shipped `.htaccess` for URL rewrites, which looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size
# fits all solution.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

Additionally I have routes defined like: `/customers/8080/edit`. Now I need to this route to be also accessible per `/customers/edit/8080`. The additional URL should rather be an alias than a simple redirect.

Because my routing is already massively complex, rewriting my routes in `module.config.php` is really no option. I thought the easiest way to achieve this would be to add rewrite conditions in my `.htaccess` and define the route `/customers/edit/8080` simply mapping to `/customers/edit/8080`.

Since ZF redirects every URL to the `index.php` I'm stuck on defining my alias routes.

Any advice would be awesome (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this problem by simply adding a literal `RewriteRule` to the `.htaccess` file. This is what I initially tried to get this working but I've been not omitting the leading slash in my pattern portion.

So this is what I came up with:

```
RewriteRule ^customers/([0-9]+)/base/edit/([0-9]+)/?$ /customers/$1/edit/base/$2 [NC,L,P]
```

Consider to specifiy the `[P]` tag, which handles requests as proxy requests, if the url should not be changed.

See also [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19368859/zend-framework-2-rewrite-url?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I'm dealing with a very similar issue, but I inherited a Zend installation, so I have no idea what the "out of the box" install looked like.

I (somewhat) solved my problem by adding a "baseURL" parameter in the `application.ini` file. See my issue and solution here, it may help. [Moving Zend Framework site to new host - "An error occurred Page not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22176181/moving-zend-framework-site-to-new-host-an-error-occurred-page-not-found)

NOTE: I'm not 100% satisfied with my results. I'm still working on it, but I'm getting close.

Comment: Thanks for the hint - I'll have a look over your solution.