# Zend Framework 2 .htaccess url issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, zend-framework2

**Problem** Using .htaccess make browser read http://some-site.somewhere.net/index/ as http://some-site.somewhere.net/.

**Issue Website Example** Accessing http://test-site.6te.net/ and trying to register. After redirecting to Authentication Page go back to http://test-site.6te.net/ and try to Log Out from dropdown menu. *It won't work*. Then go to http://test-site.6te.net/index/ and hit Log Out **boom** it works.

This issues appears because i have a Zend Framework Application. And when i access http://some-site.somewhere.net/ it appears index page but buttons requiring 'controller' and 'action' doesn't work. They work fine in http://some-site.somewhere.net/index/. Tried to add to .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^/index/?$ / [NC,L,R]
```

also tried

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ /index/ [NC,L,R]
```

as in following link [Zend Framework 2 Rewrite URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19368859/zend-framework-2-rewrite-url) . Also in module.config.php is like this:

```
<?php
return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Test\Controller\Index' =>
            'Test\Controller\IndexController',
            'Test\Controller\Register' =>
            'Test\Controller\RegisterController',
            'Test\Controller\Login' =>
            'Test\Controller\LoginController',
            'Test\Controller\Auth' =>
            'Test\Controller\AuthController',
        ),
    ),
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'test' => array(
                'type' => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' =>'Test\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Index',
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes'  => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type' => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route' =>
                            '[:controller[/:action]/]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' =>
                                '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action' =>
                                '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_map' => array(
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        ),
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'test'       => __DIR__ . '/../view',
            'doctype'    => 'HTML5',
        ),
    ),
    'user-manager' => array(
        'type' =>'Segment',
        'options' => array(
            'route' => '/user-manager[/:action[/:id]]',
            'constraints' => array(
                'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                'id' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
            ),
            'defaults' => array(
                'controller' => ' Test\Controller\UserManager',
                'action' => 'index',
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On

# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The 
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to 
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size 
# fits all solution.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Can you add the .htaccess text in the question too? Also where does 
the buttons requiring 'controller' and 'action' links redirect to?

Comment: added **.htaccess**.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve with your rewrite rule, but maybe this [htaccess file from the Zend Framework 2 Skeleton application](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/public/.htaccess) can help you out.

Otherwise please explain more in detail what the purpose of the different rewrite rule is.

### EDIT:

*Well i checked your site as suggested in your comment.*

*I don't think your problems have anything to do with your* `htaccess` *file. Your* `htaccess` *file seems to work just fine, the problem is in your links/form actions, so focus on that.*

---

I made an account. I logged in then I went to the main page. log-out didn't work from there.
Then i tried to go to the suggested `http://test-site.6te.net/index` this gave me a 404, so this route doesn't exist.
But then I went back to `http://test-site.6te.net/auth/` and there logout works fine.

I notice the following difference:

On logout on the `auth` route the logout form looks like this:

```
<form action="/Auth/logout/" method="post" name="Login" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="Login">                       
    <dd>
        <input type="submit" name="logout" class="btn btn-link" value="Log Out">
    </dd>
</form>
```

On logout on the main page the logout form looks like this:

```
<form action="/" method="post" name="LoginSm" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="LoginSm">                           
    <li>
        <button class="btn btn-link">
            <a href="auth/">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span>Restricted Area
            </a>
        </button>
    </li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li>
        <dd>
            <input type="submit" name="logout" class="btn btn-link" value="Log Out">
        </dd>
    </li>
</form>
```

So if I click logout on the first form it sends a `POST` request to `/Auth/logout/`
The second form sends a `POST` request to `/`.

So not it seems logical that you get different behavior from the two logout buttons.

I would suggest you make one solution for logging out and use it consistently in your Application.

You should also ask yourself if using a form and `POST` method for logging out is useful. I think a simple link (`GET` request) should do the job.

Comment: To fully understand my problem here is my website http://test-site.6te.net/ . Try first to register then go to main page http://test-site.6te.net/ and there will be Log out option. It doesn't work. Then try accessing http://test-site.6te.net/index/ and then hit Log Out which works. Hopefully this will make clear what i am trying to fix.

Comment: You should've tried http://test-site.6te.net/index/ not http://test-site.6te.net/index

Comment: what is the difference?

Comment: Also when i look at http://test-site.6te.net/ in small login form action is "/" but in http://test-site.6te.net/index/ it is "/login/process/

Comment: it shouldn't be any difference but it somehow changes form's action url.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60145/discussion-between-wilt-and-user3904245).